# How to use span name in logs instead of spanId in spring cloud sleuth?

Tags: logging, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth 2.0.0 M6` and due to breaking changes I cannot use my previous configuration which allows me to see the (human readable) span names in console logs instead of `spanId`s.

I want to see `[app,98ec5c2ab34ea626,span-name,false]` instead of `[app,98ec5c2ab34ea626,f56b4623ee2e9a3f,false]`

I used to configure it in `2.0.0M1` as follows:

```
class CustomSlf4jSpanLogger implements SpanLogger {


    @Override
    public void logStartedSpan(Span parent, Span span) {
        MDC.put(Span.SPAN_ID_NAME, span.getName());
        MDC.put(Span.SPAN_NAME_NAME, span.getName());
        MDC.put(Span.SPAN_EXPORT_NAME, String.valueOf(span.isExportable()));
        MDC.put(Span.TRACE_ID_NAME, span.traceIdString());
        log("Starting span: {}", span);
        if (parent != null) {
            log("With parent: {}", parent);
            MDC.put(Span.PARENT_ID_NAME, Span.idToHex(parent.getSpanId()));
        }
    }

   // the rest is omitted for brevity

}
```

Now `SpanLogger` is gone. Closest thing I could find is [Slf4jCurrentTraceContext](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/6b3593660f92f80b46d5067dc5a725a2a227142d/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/log/Slf4jCurrentTraceContext.java) however `currentSpan` which is of type `TraceContext` has no span name in it.

How can I configure this in `2.0.0 M6`?

Answer (score 0):

That's the problem... The name is not available in a Brave's span at that point. I guess you'd have to maybe add some tag or sth and try to retrieve it in `Slf4jCurrentTraceContext`. I think I wrote about this here - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-2.0-Migration-Guide#removed-features